# Android AccessibilityService ReadFile ENOENT

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions

I'm facing some problems developing an AccessibilityService.
It seems to me that the Service has no right to read the file. The file exists and it's no problem to do this within an Activity. All I want to do is playing a sound when a notification occurs. But also using notification.sound=xy; or RingtoneManager.getRingtone(,).play are not working. I could reduce the problem by using a FileInputStream to an ENOENT error, so it seem to me that the service is not allowed to read a file on non-private storage space.
A media placed in

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.siren);
```

does work. Is there any possibility to read a notification sound form internal storage by using a service?
Tested on Nexus 7 4.4 and Razr i 4.12 which results in same behavior

```
public class MyService extends AccessibilityService implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener{
    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {        
        final int eventType = event.getEventType();
        switch (eventType) {
            case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED:
                try{
                MediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
                File f = new File("/system/media/audio/notifications/Upsilon.ogg");
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
                fileInputStream.close();
                mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                }
                catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
                break;
        }
    }

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        player.start();
    }
...
}
```

This leads to the following Error:

```
02-04 16:09:29.623: W/System.err(7163): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/media/audio/notifications/Upsilon.ogg': open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-04 16:09:29.623: W/System.err(7163):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
02-04 16:09:29.623: W/System.err(7163):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
02-04 16:09:29.623: W/System.err(7163):     at com.example.examplepack.MyService.parseRawMessages(WhatsAppService.java:145)
02-04 16:09:29.623: W/System.err(7163):     at com.example.examplepack.MyService.onAccessibilityEvent(WhatsAppService.java:108)
02-04 16:09:29.623: W/System.err(7163):     at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$1.onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityService.java:556)
02-04 16:09:29.623: W/System.err(7163):     at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$IAccessibilityServiceClientWrapper.executeMessage(AccessibilityService.java:644)
02-04 16:09:29.623: W/System.err(7163):     at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:40)
02-04 16:09:29.623: W/System.err(7163):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-04 16:09:29.623: W/System.err(7163):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-04 16:09:29.623: W/System.err(7163):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-04 16:09:29.633: W/System.err(7163):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 16:09:29.633: W/System.err(7163):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-04 16:09:29.633: W/System.err(7163):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-04 16:09:29.633: W/System.err(7163):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-04 16:09:29.633: W/System.err(7163):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 16:09:29.633: W/System.err(7163): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-04 16:09:29.633: W/System.err(7163):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-04 16:09:29.633: W/System.err(7163):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-04 16:09:29.633: W/System.err(7163):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
02-04 16:09:29.633: W/System.err(7163):     ... 16 more
```

The same code works when I use it inside an Activity (not async):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    ...
    private void buttonPressed(){
            try{
                MediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
                File f = new File("/system/media/audio/notifications/Upsilon.ogg");
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
                fileInputStream.close();            
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.start();
            }
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

The Manifest:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <service
            android:name="com.example.examplepack.MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"

            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
                android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />

        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.examplepack.MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_log" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks for helping me